# Flex: tag cloud component?

Tags: apache-flex

is there any Flex component displaying tag clouds ? (Each array item is composed by
- tag name
- populairity value

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/tagClouds.png

It is very important the tags do not override each other, to keep it readable.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your looking for, but here's a basic one:

http://www.glodde.com/blog/default.aspx?id=1&t=Basic-Flex-TagCloud-Component

This guy took the above and added to it, unfortunately his domain name is expired at the moment so you can't see his demo

http://flexadmiral.com/blog/post/2008/11/18/Flex-Tag-Cloud-XML-and-External-Stylesheets-Loaded-at-Runtime.aspx

more of his work, I think this is a better polished version, but still inaccessible till the dude renews his domain:

http://groups.adobe.com/posts/6e979edbd8

This is an $8 pay for use component:

http://activeden.net/item/tag-cloud-component/41684

I think this is the best with links to source code:

http://carvalhar.com/componente/FlexCumulusTagCloud/

FYI all of these links came up searching google for "flex tag cloud"

Answer (score -1):

I have a 3 different versions of a Adobe Flex Tag Cloud. For Flex 3 I have one that uses the flexlib FlowBox component. I also created a 3D Tag Cloud similar to the one on WordPress. And a couple weeks ago, I created a Flex 4 Tag Cloud Layout that makes use of multi-line links depending on a dynamically sized container.

Here is one of the urls and you should be able to search and find the others at the same place:

Adobe Flex 4 Tag Cloud Layout

http://flexadmiral.com/blog/post/2010/07/22/Adobe-Flex-4-TagCloud-Layout-with-Multi-Line-Tags-from-XML-Data-Provider.aspx

Any or all of these might be able to help you. Let me know if I can help answer any questions.

Shawn